# Firefox performance of web pages

Tags: firefox, performance

I know a thing called firebugs exists but I am looking for any other firefox plugin that gives useful performance information.  What I would really like is something that would record my clicks and then tell them how long each one took in a very readable way.  Any tips?

Comment: What's wrong with Firebug?

Comment: It's a usability thing.  I'd like to get something that just gives me what I want in a sleeker way.

Answer (score 0):

The other half of the necessary pair of web debugging tools is fiddler. [Firebug for client side debugging]. Fiddler has great profiling tools (if you mean how long does it take each component to download  when I click on a link), scripting and monitoring of client/host web communication.
[Here's its home page.](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) Fiddler runs with all browsers you have currently installed.